# Splitting object data into new columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

i have a dataframe with column business_id and attributes with thousands of rows like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|                                                                         attributes |        business_id|
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|{"WiFi":"u'free","HasTV":"False","RestaurantsTableService":"True","Caters":"True".. |6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q|
|{"HasTV:"False","Ambience":{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False,},"Price":"2" .... |7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

how do create new column for each attribute with the value to the business id ? and if it's not applicable to that business id, it will specify false.

example:

```
+---------------+-------------+-------------------+
|           Wifi|        Price|        business_id|
+---------------+-------------+-------------------+
|         u'free|        False|6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q|
|          False|            2|7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa|
+---------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

while also noting that there are some attributes with value as object in an object like:

```
{..."Ambience":{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False}...}
```

for this, if possible, i would like to tag that values to the attribute like as the column name like:

```
Ambience.romantic
```

Would someone please help me with this if you know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to each of the `dict`s in `attributes`.

**Update**: if the elements in `attributes` are JSON strings, then we need to turn them into dict first. The following function will do that (and also accept `dict`):

```py
import json

def json_normalize(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        s = json.loads(s)
    return pd.json_normalize(s)
```

Now, use this instead of `pd.json_normalize()` directly:

```py
df2 = pd.concat(df['attributes'].apply(json_normalize).to_list(),
                keys=df.business_id)
>>> df2
                         WiFi  HasTV RestaurantsTableService Caters Price  \
business_id                                                                 
6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q 0  u'free  False                    True   True   NaN   
7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa 0     NaN  False                     NaN    NaN     2   

                      Ambience.romantic Ambience.intimate  
business_id                                                
6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q 0               NaN               NaN  
7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa 0             False             False
```

Note, the above follows a **reproducible setup**:

```py
# first, reproducible setup, with dicts
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'attributes': [
        {"WiFi":"u'free","HasTV":"False","RestaurantsTableService":"True","Caters":"True"},
        {"HasTV":"False", "Ambience":{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False,},"Price":"2"},
    ],
    'business_id': ['6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q', '7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa'],
})

# or, with strings
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'attributes': [
        """{"WiFi":"free","HasTV":"False","RestaurantsTableService":"True","Price":"3"}""",
        """{"HasTV":"False","Ambience":{"romantic": "False", "intimate": "False"},"Price":"2"}""",
    ],
    'business_id': ['6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q', '7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa'],
})
```

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. however, i am facing 'str' object has no attribute 'values' error. upon checking, the attributes object is a string. how do i go about this?

Comment: not a problem, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `attribute` string is a **valid JSON**, you can extract a single JSON value using [`get_json_object`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object) like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('''{"WiFi":"free","HasTV":"False","RestaurantsTableService":"True","Price":"3"}''', '6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q'),
    ('''{"HasTV":"False","Ambience":{"romantic": "False", "intimate": "False"},"Price":"2"}''', '7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa'),
], ['attributes', 'business_id'])

(df
    .withColumn('price', F.get_json_object('attributes', '$.Price'))
    .withColumn('has_tv', F.get_json_object('attributes', '$.HasTV'))
    .select('price', 'has_tv', 'business_id')
    .show(10, False)
)

+-----+------+-------------------+
|price|has_tv|business_id        |
+-----+------+-------------------+
|3    |False |6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0q|
|2    |False |7f4z43MHAV-l-LsRYsa|
+-----+------+-------------------+
```